# CardBoard: In 360 video, how can I use both gesture and device movement together?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, rajawali, 360-degrees, rajawalivr

I have been stuck on this issue for a week.

Currently, I'm able to control it with gesture using `Matrix4.setLookAt()` function. I'm able to control it by moving around the device.

However, I tried to combined **both** gesture and device movement together. When I swipe up/down, the gesture will start to move the screen at an angle (down and left, up and right). Here is the video demonstration:
[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saV5aJK4u1M&feature=youtu.be)

I'm new to camera matrix. Can anyone give me advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Wesley nope, I haven't found any solution yet. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?